# getting one estimate from multiple teams

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

table: estimates

```
id | team_id | project_id | value | type
```

What I want to achieve is only the latest value of one estimate type.

Types are  1, 2 or 3

Lets say we have **project_id 1** with estimate **type 1**, **team_id 8** with a **value 20** and another one with  **project_id 1**  **team_id 8**  **type 2** and a **value 80**

The only thing I want to see is the value 80 of project_id 1 for team 8.

Any ideas?

Comment: How have you determined that the second record in your example is the "*latest*" one?  Is it because it has the maximal value for `type`?

Comment: Indeed, the highest type number is the most important one, so if estimate type 3 is available we should show this estimate else type 2 or 1

Comment: `SELECT value FROM estimates WHERE project_id = 1 AND team_id = 8 ORDER BY type DESC LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.value, e.team_id, e.project_id
  FROM estimates e
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(type_id) AS type_id
                  , team_id
                  , project_id
               FROM estimates 
           GROUP BY team_id, project_id
           ) mx ON (    mx.team_id = e.team_id 
                    AND mx.project_id = e.project_id
                    AND mx.type_id = e.type_id
                   )
```